# Combining a list of named vectors without mangling the names

Tags: r

How do I combine a list of named vectors?  I need to split a vector of integers (with characters for names) for use with `parallel::parSapply()` and combine them back again. Example code:

```
text <- 1:26
names(text) <- letters
n <- 4
text <- split(text, cut(1:length(text),breaks=n,labels=1:n))
# text <- parSapply(..., text, ...) would go here in the actual code
```

However, the names get mangled when I use `unlist` to convert the data back into a named vector:

```
> unlist(text)
1.a 1.b 1.c 1.d 1.e 1.f 1.g 2.h 2.i 2.j 2.k 2.l 2.m 3.n 3.o 3.p 3.q 3.r 3.s 4.t 4.u 4.v 
  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22 
4.w 4.x 4.y 4.z 
 23  24  25  26
```

What I'm looking for is the following result (except that it should work with any value of *n*):

```
> c(text[[1]],text[[2]],text[[3]],text[[4]])
 a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  t  u  v  w  x  y  z 
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
```

Comment: `unlist(unname(text))` is a good one. Or `Reduce(c, text)` would also work.

Comment: @RichardScriven Both are good options.  You should have provided that as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option without changing the structure of 'text' would be to change the names of the `vector` (`unlist(text)`) with the `names` of onjects within the `list` elements.

```
setNames(unlist(text), unlist(sapply(text, names)))
#  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  t  u  v  w  x  y  z 
#  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
```

Or if it is okay to remove the names of the 'text' object, set the names of 'text' to NULL and then `unlist`

```
unlist(setNames(text, NULL))
#  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  t  u  v  w  x  y  z 
# 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
```

Comment: `unname(...)` seems simpler than `setNames(...,NULL)`

Comment: @thelatemail Yes, it is, but RichardScriven already mentioned it.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the list elements names first then there won't be compound naming happening.

```
> names(text) <- NULL
> do.call(c, text)
 a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  t  u  v  w  x  y  z 
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
```

Same as

```
> unlist(text)
 a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  t  u  v  w  x  y  z 
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
```

Or as @RichardScriven pointed out in the comment, you can do it as follows without removing the name in the source variable: `do.call("c", c(text, use.names = FALSE))`

Comment: Or `do.call("c", c(text, use.names = FALSE))` for a single call, leaving `text` unchanged.